# Magento catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1 AddOption SOAP

Tags: magento2.2, xml, soap

I am sending a soap request to Magento and getting an error per below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<soap:Envelope xmlns:def="XXX/soap/all? 
services=catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1" 
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  -<soap:Body>
  -<def:catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1AddRequest>
    <attributeCode>edition</attributeCode>
    -<option>
      <sort_order>0</sort_order>
      <is_default>false</is_default>
      <label>Test10</label>
      <value/>
    </option>
  </def:catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1AddRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response is as per below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<env:Envelope xmlns:m="XXX%2Fsoap%2Fall%3Fservices%3DcatalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1%26wsdl%3D1" xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  -<env:Body>
  -<env:Fault>
  -<env:Code>
    <env:Value>env:Sender</env:Value>
  </env:Code>
  -<env:Reason>
    <env:Text xml:lang="en">Attribute %1 doesn't work with options</env:Text>
    </env:Reason>
  -<env:Detail>
-<m:GenericFault>
-<m:Parameters>
-<m:GenericFaultParameter>
  <m:key>1</m:key>
  <m:value>edition</m:value>
</m:GenericFaultParameter> 
</m:Parameters>
</m:GenericFault>
</env:Detail>
</env:Fault>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I have tried using catalogProductAttributeAddOption method, catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1AddPostBody method, catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1Add method. Please assist if a tag is missing or if I am using the wrong method?

T.I.A

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to add the option to a text/visual swatch attribute by modifying my request xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:def="XXX/soap/all?services=catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Body>
  <def:catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1AddRequest>
    <attributeCode>test</attributeCode>
    <option>
      <sortOrder>0</sortOrder>
      <isDefault>false</isDefault>
      <label>Test123</label>
      <value/>
      <color>Blue</color>
   </option>
 </def:catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1AddRequest>
 </soap:Body>
```

OR

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:def="XXX/soap/all?services=catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Body>
  <def:catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1AddRequest>
    <attributeCode>test</attributeCode>
    <option>
      <sortOrder>0</sortOrder>
      <isDefault>false</isDefault>
      <label>Test123</label>
      <value/>
      <swatchvisual>
        <value>#e6db09</value>
      </swatchvisual>
   </option>
 </def:catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1AddRequest>
 </soap:Body>
```

The only issue I hav now is that the value(hex) is not updating the swatch:
[image]